# Universal Windows Development JavaScript support for WebRTC?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, webrtc, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I just wanted to know if it were possible to implement the webRTC and sip.js libraries on the universal windows (10) platform using either UWP or Cordova.

Would I be able to use any .js libraries or APIs?

I'm using visual studio 2015.

Thanks

Comment: if you've found this answer to be helpful and correct, please mark it as so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows 10 JavaScript app is going to use Edge as the browser under the hood whether or not you are using Cordova.

[Edge currently supports ORTC](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/09/18/ortc-api-is-now-available-in-microsoft-edge/) (dubbed WebRTC2), but not WebRTC.

Whichever JS libraries work in Edge, will work in your Win 10 app.

Feel free to ping me with additional questions.